# How do you get a position:absolute; element above a position:relative; one

Tags: html, css

You can see the issue in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sonicblis/d03sgffr/2/).

I've got an absolutely positioned element with a z-index of 2 and a relatively positioned element with a z-index of 1.  The relatively positioned element contains the absolutely positioned one.  I thought that the z-index:2 element would show above the z-index:1 items, but it does not.  Is there a way to fix this so that the z-index:2 items are above all z-index:1 items?

```css
div {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

span {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Row 1
  <span>I thought this would show above 'Row 2'</span>
</div>
<div>
  Row 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add a `z-index` to a child that is in a positioned parent element that also has a `z-index`, the parent `z-index` starts a new stacking order, and the child `z-index` is relative to the parent's `z-index`. So in this case, `z-index: 2` is only compared to other elements inside of the parent with `z-index: 1`. To get around this, you could just apply the `z-index` to the `span`, or don't give the last `div` a `z-index`

You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

* {
  padding: 10px;
}

div {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  
}

div:first-child {
  z-index: 1;
}

span {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Row 1
  <span>
  I thought this would show above 'Row 2'
</span>
</div>
<div>
  Row 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because the div with absolute position was not relative to the second row. I added a wrapper around the two divs and added `position: relative;` to it.

```css
.wrapper div {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

span {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    Row 1
    <span>I thought this would show above 'Row 2'</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Row 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `z-index:1`.

```css
div {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Row 1
  <span>I thought this would show above 'Row 2'</span>
</div>
<div>
  Row 2
</div>
```